# Terraform: What are the alternatives to connect to existing ec2 instance avoiding remote-exec provisioner

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have some queries on the usage of the "remote-exec" provisioner on an existing ec2 instance.
I am connecting to an ubuntu ec2 using an ssh connection, to execute a script. Below is the sample code to do so:-

```
resource "null_resource" "cwa_setup_on_existing_ec2" {
  for_each = toset(local.cw_existing_instance_watchlist)

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("priv_key")}"
    host        = each.value.instance_info.public_ip
    timeout     = "4m"
  }

  provisioner "file"{
    source = "user_data.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/user_data.sh"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo '----- Executing cwa-setup script on already initialized ec2 ------- '",
    "chmod +x /tmp/user_data.sh",
    "cd /tmp",
    "./user_data.sh >> cwa-setup.log" ]
  }
}
```

I am copying the script to ec2 using file provisioner first and then executing it. The execution succeeds and looks safe to connect with my own private key.
But I need to able to connect (via Terraform) to set of existing instances created with multiple user's private keys in **the root account**. Its insecure and infeasible to provide private keys for other users by loading them from disk.
Thus summing up the concerns :-

1. What is the better way(s) to connect to existing ec2 via terraform?
2. Terraform documentation suggests using Provisioners as a last resort and using better alternatives. What are the alternative ways to run a script on a remote instance without compromising secure access?

Comment: 1. user_data when provided actually as userdata will execute on bootup, so you odn't need to connect. 2. With cloud-init userdata and/or prebuilding your OS images.

Comment: @jordanm comment is absolutely correct answer with additional footnote about Packer for the image build.

Comment: Ansible (https://www.ansible.com/) is a good alternative that I have used in the past

Comment: @jordanm Yes, you are right. I am already using user_data option for new instances and cloud-init works so well. But I need to support some existing instances which are running since long. In that case, I need to remotely connect to them. I guess, there has to be some better way to connect to existing instances.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way in this case. Since you already understand the benefit of using cloud-init for instance resource, ssh with remote provisioner is the best option if you have to use terraform after creation where cloud-init is no longer an option. You can avoid ssh key usage by using the session manager plugin with iam, but not so easy in this case I don't think.

Comment: Maybe you could use the [session manager plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html) with [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec), but that is pretty sloppy and relies on too much outside terraform.

Comment: @theherk thanks for the response, will try the session manager plugin..